# how do i sort a .txt file filled with formatted dates

Tags: python, datetime

I have a .txt file called dates.txt. It has code like this in it like this

```
Fri Jan 31 05:51:59 +0000 2014
Fri Jan 31 05:01:39 +0000 2014
Thu Jan 30 14:31:21 +0000 2014
Sat Feb 01 06:53:10 +0000 2014
```

How do i sort these by dates by oldest to newest? I'm pretty sure you have to use datetime and strptime functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt


def sortFile(infilepath, outfilepath, fmt):
    lines = []
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            lines.append(dt.strptime(line, fmt))  # parse the time, and read in the file

    lines.sort()  # sort the datetime objects
    with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line.stftime(fmt))  # write out the datetime objects with the parsing format
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
sortFile('path/to/input', /path/to/output', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y\n")
```